# Fulfillment URL is not valid in Dialogflow | Using Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es

I was using Dialogflow API V1 until now and everything was working fine. It seems like the Dialogflow API V2 is now the default. I am not sure if this is the reason but I am not able to deploy cloud functions anymore.

In the fulfillment tab, it is not letting me enabled the cloud function toggle. Every time I try to enable and click deploy it gives me the following error:

> Fulfillment URL is not valid

It's weird because I am not using fulfillment URL and still I am getting this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that worked for me when. I wanted to create a back up bot for my existing LIVE bot to use it for testing. I was getting the same issue once I restored my zip and after that try to edit the stock fulfillment.

What worked for me was, I edited the fulfillment first .index.js and package.json both after which I restored the bot using zip folder that added  intents and entities to the agent. after which I was able to deploy cloud functions without getting the error.